# How to compare a NUMBER with VARCHAR2 type number having leading zeroes?

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, type-conversion, varchar

I am trying to compare two columns in two different tables in a database. One column is of type VARCHAR2(4 CHAR) and the other is of type DECIMAL. Although I am pulling these columns into JAVA as a string to do the comparison, I am running into this issue:

Elements in column (decimal) are: 123, 456, 789

Elements of compared column (varchar) are: 0123, 0456, 0789

So I want to know if there is a way that I can remove this prefixed 0 as I am pulling it from the database (like some sort of TRIM0()) such that elements from both columns would be the same?

I am trying to avoid handling this column in the JAVA itself to improve performance.

Comment: your issue will be solved if you compare two integers. I suggest you to transfer the varchars to int

Comment: I say the same, use same numeric data type in both places! LTRIM(column, '0')

Comment: @jarlh There is no point in using `LTRIM` here. LTRIM on a string would return a string. Simply use `TO_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (like some sort of TRIM0()) such that elements from both columns would be the same?

**Your requirement is about data type conversion, not string manipulation.**

Elements might look similar, but it is the **data type** that matters. `'123'` and `123` are not the same. They look similar, but they are different data types.

Do not use **LTRIM** as it would return you a **STRING**, you will have to convert it to **NUMBER** again to avoid **implicit data type conversion**. It is pointless to return a string, and then use TO_NUMBER again to convert it to number.

The correct and efficient way is to use **TO_NUMBER**. It would convert it into NUMBER in just one step.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT to_number('00123') num FROM dual;

       NUM
----------
       123

SQL> SELECT * FROM dual WHERE to_number('00123') = 123;

D
-
X
```

On a side note, if you are sure that always need a **NUMBER** from the column to process, then you must fix it at **design level**. Storing *numbers* as *character type* is a **design flaw**, unless there is a specific *business need*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LTRIM to remove the leading zeroes from the varchar number:

```
select ltrim( '0001234', '0' ) from dual;
```

But I would suggest revisiting your design and comparing number to number.

Comment: **The requirement is about data type conversion, not string manipulation.** So, your answer doesn't completely serves the requirement. `LTRIM` of a string would return a **string**. So, you would end up **comparing a string with number**. It is a performance overhead to depend on **implicit data type conversion**. You could do it in one step using `TO_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try casting but I believe this will hurt the performance of the query. And it will prob cause issues if there is ever a letter in one

```
where cast(column1 as unsigned) = cast(column2 as unsigned)
```

Comment: A shorter version of casting it as a number would be using `TO_NUMBER`. Although you are on the right track, as the primary requirement is to deal with the data type converesion and not string manipulation.